# Find array with last value equal 0

Tags: php, arrays

In a given array I want find the first key that has a zero value from that key until the end of the array. For example:

```
$data1 = array(
        '1 Jan|8:30' => '12.6',
        '2 Feb|8:30' => '250',
        '3 Mar|8:10' => '0',
        '4 Apr|23:30' => '7',
        '5 Apr|23:30' => '80',
        '6 Apr|23:30' => '67',
        '7 r|23:30' => '0',
        '8 Ap|23:30' => '0',
        '9 Lr|23:30' => '0',
        '10 Apr|23:30' => '0'
);

// outcome should: be '7 r|23:30' => '0'
```

And:

```
$data2 = array(
    '1 Jan|8:30' => '12.6',
    '2 Feb|8:30' => '250',
    '3 Mar|8:10' => '0',
    '4 Apr|23:30' => '7',
    '5 Apr|23:30' => '80',
    '6 Apr|23:30' => '67',
    '7 r|23:30' => '0',
    '8 Ap|23:30' => '0',
    '9 Lr|23:30' => '1',
    '10 Apr|23:30' => '0'
);

// outcome should be: '10 Apr|23:30' => '0'
```

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: i want find a array with value = 0 but afer this don't have other array like value =0

Comment: Do you mean element (as in you want to find which element in your array has a value equal to zero)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate the array backwards until the value is no longer `'0'`:

```
$key = null;

for ($value = end($arr); $value !== false && $value == '0'; $value = prev($arr)) {
    $key = key($arr); // keep track of current key
}

if ($key !== null) {
    echo $key, ' = ', $arr[$key];
}
```